# Query datasource referencing other datasources

Tags: google-app-maker

I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach here; I have two data models, CoursesFiled and TraineesFiled. They both have a field called CourseName. Each Trainee record will have a CourseName field that also appears in CoursesFiled.

The end product needs to be two pages. On the first, there is a table with all the courses. One is selected, and this takes the user to the next page, where a table displays all the Trainees in the selected course.

I'm somewhat new to this and figured the easiest would be to set up a query datasource on the TraineesFiled model, with a query script that looks like this:

```
var courseName = "Register-2012-10-02(xxxxxxxxx).xml";//hardcoded for now, to be replaced with variable being passed from UI for app.datasources.CoursesFiled.item.CourseName;
var query = app.models.TraineesFiled.newQuery();
query.filters.CourseName._equals = courseName ;
query.run();
```

When I create a new table with the query-datasouce as it's datasource, it loads with the following error:

```
Fri Oct 12 10:59:46 GMT+200 2018
The function queryRecords returned undefined, please make sure a value was 
explicitly returned. Error: The function queryRecords returned undefined, 
please make sure a value was explicitly returned.
E
Fri Oct 12 10:59:46 GMT+200 2018
Executing query for datasource TraineesFiled1: (Error) : The function 
queryRecords returned undefined, please make sure a value was explicitly 
returned.
E
Fri Oct 12 10:59:46 GMT+200 2018
Executing query for datasource TraineesFiled1 failed.
```

Where am I going wrong? Am I completely going about this in the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the **[official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/datasources#query_script)**, when using a query script, you need to ***RETURN*** the results.

> For example, let's say that you want to only return employees whose age is an even number and apply a minimum age specified in the query. You could write the following code snippet in the Query Script code editor:

```
var employeeResult = [];
// Modify passed query to additionally filter by minimum age.
query.filters.Age._greaterThan = 20;
var employeesAboveMinimumAge = query.run();
for (var i = 0; i < employeesAboveMinimumAge.length; i++) {
  if (employeesAboveMinimumAge[i].age % 2 == 0) {
    employeeResult.push(employeesAboveMinimumAge[i]);
  }
}
return employeeResult;
```

This means that all you have to do, is add a **return** statement to your code:

```
var courseName = "Register-2012-10-02(xxxxxxxxx).xml";
var query = app.models.TraineesFiled.newQuery();
query.filters.CourseName._equals = courseName ;
return query.run();
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That works :) I did find an easier way, however, using query builder. I set the query to CourseName = :MyParameter, and then bound the MyParameter to "@datasources.CoursesFiled.item.CourseName". But good to know how both approaches work.